# How get this effect with color filter in Android

Tags: android, imageview, colorfilter

I would like to know how pass from this :

[image]

To this :

[image]

By using colorFilter on my ImageView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ImageView.setAlpha(float)` (between 0-1)

Comment: you are welcome, could you set the answer as correct? :)